# Vectorize a matrix per row

Tags: r, vector, matrix, vectorization

I'd like ot vectorize a matrix in order to get the values "per rows". For example:

```
mat = matrix(1:4,ncol=2)
mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

c(mat) # or as.vector(mat). Both give the values "per columns"
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

I would like to get this:

```
[1] 1 3 2 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose your matrix first, such as `c(t(mat))`.

Answer (score -2):

Fill matrix by row

```
matrix(1:4,ncol=2 , byrow=TRUE)  # matrix is filled by rows.
```

[image]

Comment: @shakthydoss there are better ways to do that. Check out [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) for examples/ideas/methods.